# Mouse pointer realtime in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a div that consistently show the position of the mouse. The problem is that the previous position is not cleared and this overload the page.
The javascript code is as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {document.onmousemove = muestraInformacion2;}
function muestraInformacion2(elEvento) {
var evento = elEvento || window.event;
var coordenadaX = evento.clientX;
var coordenadaY = evento.clientY;
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML +=
 "<br>--------------------------------------<br>" + coordenadaX+", "+coordenadaY
```

Comment: sajad solution should work, just wanted to point out is that you might want to put some kind of timeout on the change because the event will be fired too many times and that can effect performance of your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your last line to

```
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML ="";
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
 "<br>--------------------------------------<br>" + coordenadaX+", "+coordenadaY
```

Comment: @AndoniAlda: please click the arrow on the left of my answer to mark my answer as accepted :) you are welcome :)

Comment: @AndoniAlda : ok..fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "+=". This should work:

```
   window.onload = function() {document.onmousemove = muestraInformacion2;}
    function muestraInformacion2(elEvento) {
    var evento = elEvento || window.event;
    var coordenadaX = evento.clientX;
    var coordenadaY = evento.clientY;
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML ="";
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
     "<br>--------------------------------------<br>" + coordenadaX+", "+coordenadaY
```

The problem is that you are constantly adding the line (the given string) to the  page. But you want to have it as the only data in the innerhtml.